# Background-image, padding and border

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` filled with a background image. I am able to add a black border. But now, I want to have a padding around the background image, but it seems like a background color of white. How do I do this like the example below?

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the background property `background-origin: content-box`

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfgcpszy/)

Comment: That is quite elegant and much easier than my solution. The only thing I can say about mine is that it works in IE8.

Comment: Sosa, thank you very much. +1 for the simplicity solution. This is quite elegant if I use it with relative background image. But the background image I set is the one to pan the image with zoom position. And the css which is working to do this is the style that Mr. Lister give bellow.

Comment: @iyal You should accept what works for you. Hey, if you need to write something yourself, even if you base it on the concepts given here, you can post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Not with a singular HTML element, but if you can spare the `::before` pseudo element of the div, it's possible.

Move the div down and to the right by the width of the white border, then make the `::before` larger than the div itself by twice the width of the border.

```css
.backgrounded {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300);
  position: relative;
  left: 8px;
  top: 8px;
  color:black; text-shadow:1px 1px white;
}
.backgrounded:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 414px;
  height: 314px;
  position: absolute;
  left:-8px; top:-8px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgrounded">This is the div</div>
```